# Upper and Lower Darboux integral of a piecewise function $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $0<a<b$. Find the upper and lower Darboux integrals for the function $$f(x)=x$$ if $x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $$f(x)=0$$ if $x\in[a,b]-\mathbb{Q}$.

I am so lost on this problem. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what any subdivision in any partition of $[a,b]$ must contain?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Start with something easy. What are $\sup f, \inf f $ over $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 2):

Any interval in any subdivision of $[a,b]$ must contain a rational and irrational point, since the intervals are not singletons nor empty. This is because the irrationals and rationals are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$. We then have that the supremum of $f$ on any non-empty, non-singleton closed interval $[x,y]$ is $\sup[x,y] = y$ and the infimum of $f$ on any interval is $0$.

So the upper sum of any uniform partition $P_n:a=t_0< t_1< ...<t_n=b$, with $t_k = a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}$ must be $$U(f,P_n) =\sum_{k=1}^{n} (t_k-t_{k-1}) t_k=\sum^{n}_{k=1} (\frac{b-a}{n}) (t_k)=\sum^{n}_{k=1} (\frac{b-a}{n})(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}) = \sum^{n}_{k=1} (a(\frac{b-a}{n})+(\frac{b-a}{n})\frac{k(b-a)}{n}) = a(b-a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}\sum^{n}_{k=1} k $$

$$= a(b-a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}\frac{1}{2} (n)(n+1)= a(b-a) + \frac{1}{2} (b-a)^2(1+\frac{1}{n})  $$

since the supremum of any interval must be on the right hand side.

Now take the infimum of all the upper sums of the uniform partitions, and you'll note that it is, $$a(b-a) + \frac{1}{2} (b-a)^2(1) = ab-a^2 + \frac{1}{2}b^2-ab+\frac{1}{2}a^2 = \frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{2}a^2$$

So the upper integral is at most $$\frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{2}a^2$$.

If $Q = \{q_0,...,q_N\}$ is any partition of $[a,b]$, then

$$U(f, Q) = \sum_{i=1}^N q_i (q_i-q_{i-1}) =  \sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 -\sum_{i=1}^Nq_i q_{i-1} \geq \sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N (q_i^2 + q_{i-1}^2) $$$$= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N (q_i^2 - q_{i-1}^2) =\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^N q_{i-1}^2) = \frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)$$

The inequality is because:

$$(x-y)^2 \geq 0 \implies x^2-2xy+y^2 \geq 0 \implies -2xy \geq -x^2-y^2 $$$$\implies 2xy \leq x^2 +y^2 \implies xy \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$$

The last equality is because the squares cancel (telescoping sum) for all $q_i \neq a,b$.

So the upper integral is at least $\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)$ since it is the greatest lower bound of the upper sums of all the partitions.

Hence the upper integral is  $\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)$.

The lower sum of any partition of $[a,b]$ must be $0$ as the infimum on any of the subintervals is $0$.

So the supremum of the lower sums over any partition must be $0$. Hence the lower integral is $0$.

Does that get you started?

Comment: Technically this only handles the problem for the case of a uniform partition. It also has some typos. It's on the right track, though.

Comment: @Ian does it make more sense now?

Comment: It's close enough now. There is a little bit of technical work to extend from uniform partitions to general partitions, but you've written the main ideas. One thing you might say is that the piecewise constant functions being integrated in the upper sums converge to $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @Ian I think I managed to extend it to all partitions. Can you check it please? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know $t_k = a+ \frac{k(b-a)}{n}$?

Comment: @DavidSouth That's by the definition of a uniform partition - you've divided the interval $[a,b]$ into equally sized subintervals. This is not true for general partitions, and the rest of the argument *should* cover that, but you should check.

Comment: Just popped in my mind: we can also use that if $x>y$, then $2x(x-y)>x^2-y^2$ since $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$. This might be useful because it generalizes directly to $f(x)=x^n$ case, purely by observing that $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots +xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ which implies $x^{n} (x-y)>\frac{1}{n+1}(x^{n+1}-y^{n+1})$. Then, the upper Darboux integral is, by the same procedure, $\frac{1}{n+1}(b^{n+1}-a^{n+1})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyse the upper sum: $U_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - x_{i-1})M_i$ where $M_i = \sup_{x\in[x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)$. So, we have to look for a $\sup$ for any interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, any interval contains rational numbers, and hence, $\sup f(x)$ is equal to $x_i$ (even if $x_i$ is irrational, there is a sequence of rational numbers with $x_i$ as its limit). Looks a lot like a Riemann sum for a function $f(x) = x$. So, your upper integral should look like $\frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}$.

With the same reasoning, you find out that the lower integral would be $0$.